# Master-detail and MVVM in iOS

Tags: ios, mvvm, uiviewcontroller, viewmodel, master-detail

I have a viewController (master) that manages a `tableView` and holds a viewModel for the tableView's data and the business logic. When user taps on a cell, it navigates to another viewController (detail) where the specific info of the selected item is shown.

The master viewController creates the detail's viewModel with the selected info, and passes it to the detail viewController. Then once the detail viewController is shown, the user can edit the information of such item. I'm using `CoreData` to persist those user's changes. So, when user edits the item, that item is updated regarding `CoreData` and the detail viewController's viewModel, but then the user can navigate back to the master viewController again. The changes done in the item should be reflected on its corresponding cell in the master viewController.

My question is: according to MVVM design pattern (viewControllers hold viewModels instead of model directly), how should I update the master viewController and its viewModel after having edited an item in the detail's viewController?

A) Who should notify whom of the changes in the model?: should the detail VC notify the master VC, and then the master VC update its VM?

B) Should the detail VM notify the master VC?

C) Should the detail VM notify the master VM?

D) How should I notify, implementing a protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

C) Should the detail VM notify the master VM?

YES!

D) How should I notify, implementing a protocol?

YES!

You should pass Master's VM as delegate to Detail's VM. So that Detail can update master's VM about the change. I suppose you are not using bindings.

Comment: Then I imagine I need a didSet{} observer in the VM's model to notify the VC it should update the UI?

Comment: I am not sure that didSet method will be called or not on updating single element's value.

Comment: How should then the VM notify its corresponding VC that has changed and the VC has to update the View?

Comment: Using Delegate Pattern